# is there a single event object for both keydown & keyup

Tags: javascript

We would like to raise a flag variable within `keydown` event object, and capture it within `keyup` is this possible to do so without using an outside variable?

Example :

```
var keydown = e => {
   e.flag = true;
}

var keyup = e => {
   e.flag // undefined
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',keydown);
document.addEventListener('keyup',keyup);
```

The problem is that it seems not to be the same event being fired for both keyup and keydown...

we know we can...

```
var flag = false;

var keydown = e => {
   flag = true;
}

var keyup = e => {
   if( flag ) // do something
}
```

Both this seems less clean rather then using the event itself...

is there anyway to get a single event object for both keydown / keyup?

Comment: `change` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: This may be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to solve with the keyup/down events?

Comment: @Satif that's only for inputs, not necessarily for arbitrary elements.

Comment: MDN lists [three keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent): keydown, keyup, and keypress.  [Keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is deprecated though and its use isn't recommended.

Comment: @Satif - `change` event fires on blur, for inputs - nothing to do with keys being pressed up, down or otherwise. @levi - I would just stick to using outside variables. It's easy and it works. Alternatively, if it is something specific to a particular field, you could set a property of the field itself using, for example, `this.keyPressed = true`.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy `change` event fires on an input being changed by the user, not on blur. The `blur` event fires on blur. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: The `change` event is not tracking state.  I would say you are trying to implement an anti-pattern.  You should not embed the state in the event data.  And where would that be maintained anyways?  The event is not persisted between calls. In most cases you want to know which key is being pressed, so it makes sense to have an independent state variable, and in most cases it won't be a simple flag for any kb press... `const kbState = {}; keyUp = e => kbState[e.code] = false; keyDown = e => kbState[e.code] = true;  ... if(kbState['KeyA']) console.log('moving left'); ... `

Comment: @StephenMIrving - please give it a go on the link that you provided and you will find that it is when you click outside the box or press tab that the area below the input is populated with the value you entered - i.e. when you 'blur' the input, the change event fires.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Ok, I just misunderstood you then, my mistake. It sounded like you meant that the `change` event fires when any `input` element is blurred, as in that being the only requirement for the event to trigger. Did not realize you meant that when the input is blurred that is the point at which the event triggers, not that it is the sole cause of it.

Comment: @EricLease thanks for the comment but my need is really a simple flag for a specific event, don't see a reason to "pollute" any outer context for this, maybe there should be a more general event for all sort of clicks (both mouse and keyboard) with a simple event phase variable or some sort...

Comment: @levi unfortunately, you can't make a shared variable that is not available in an outside scope. However, you can wrap the two event handlers and bindings in a closure and you'd isolate that variable from  being accessible outside.